# peewee.ImproperlyConfigured: Postgres driver not installed

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi, peewee

I have installed peewee and postgres. I am using FastAPI as the backend. When I run the request to create tables, it throws the shown error:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:33284 - "GET /setup_db HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
peewee.ImproperlyConfigured: Postgres driver not installed!
```

This is my main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from models.schema import db, User, Plan
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import *

db = PostgresqlDatabase('database_name', host='localhost', port=5432, user='user', password='password')

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def Home():
    return "Welcome Home"

@app.get('/setup_db')
async def SetupDB():
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([User],[Plan])

    new_user = User.create(
        username = 'user1',
        email = 'user1@email.com',
        hashed_password = 'pwd####',
        create_on = datetime(2001, 3, 29, 5, 15, 30)
    )
    print(new_user)
    return new_user
```

I tried importing the Models from different folders but it did not work. Please let me know what drivers/config do I need to add to make this work. Thanks & Cheers!

Comment: can you share `models` package or `schema` file contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install postgresql driver:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

But, I suggest you to use more robust solution, like: `sqlalchemy`, `asyncpg`,  `alembic` :)